# How should I prepare the database of the counter counting down in seconds with php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up counter logic for a game. The critical point here is that every user who enters this page sees the same second at that moment. I will have a counter that counts down from 25 and everyone will place their bets during this time. When the 25 seconds are over, a 10 second counter will start, during which 10 seconds the winning bet will be announced. How can I set up the database setup so that these counters are repeated continuously?

I am using the following code for javascript, but every time I enter the page it starts from 25

```
var interval = 25000;
var interval1 = 10000;
var endTime;

function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
    // Use floor instead of toFixed
    var seconds = Math.floor((millis % 60000) / 1000);
    return (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
}

function reset() {
    // Use Date.now() instead of +new Date()
    // And create a cycle length that covers both intervals
    endTime = Date.now() + interval + interval1;
}

reset();
setInterval(function () {
    var remaining = endTime - Date.now();
    if (remaining >= 0) {
        // Adjust the time to display 
        // depending on where in the total interval we are:
        if (remaining >= interval1) remaining -= interval1;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerText =
            millisToMinutesAndSeconds(remaining);
    } else {
        reset()
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: what tables do you have inplace right now ?

Comment: I haven't created yet. I just don't understand how to do database setup for counter @jmvcollaborator

Comment: you might not need to put the timer on the database, just in the application code should be enough

Comment: This is impossible in pure php. php is not a language able to implement real time solutions. Simply because the web technology is not suited for that. You'd need to use a _client side_ logic here for synchronization. That may indeed rely on a server side counter, but that is not required. It is easier to simply define a target timestamp and use the current time to measure against that. But definitely on the client side, so in javascript.

Comment: I added a code to my question, but the counter always restarts, how can I prevent this? @arkascha

Comment: Why do you ask me? I told you that this is not possible with the approach you chose.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the end date and time in database. The countdown must be done with javascript.

Get the date from backend (database) with php and pass it to javascript. Then do the countdown with js.

[This tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/creating-countdown-in-php-javascript-mysql/) seems exactly like what you need.

Comment: what you say is for an application that will end on a certain date. So you say to write the end date to the database and subtract it from the current time and print it to the counter. That's not what I'm talking about. What I want is a counter that will run continuously. It looks like it will work backwards for 25 seconds, then count down for 10 seconds, then run for 25 seconds again. @Optimizr

Comment: Why do you need it to be in database if it is just for 25 seconds? Why don't you just show the example website instead of typing.